# Assert.Equals fails when comparing the same type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I'm running into an issue where a test is failing when running but succeeds when breaking into the test.

```
Assert.Equals(typeof(Plugin.Plugin), plugin.GetType());
```

When running the test the guids are different.  The typeof call returns a guid of all zeroes while the GetType has the expected guid.  If I set a breakpoint to that line the guids match.  Has anyone encountered this?  They are both coming from the same assembly so they should both match.  This is using .net 461

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the plugin variable is an instance of the Plugin class and not an instance of a derived class ?

Comment: No I'm sure it is.  A bunch of colleagues at work looked at this and we can't figure out why this is happening.  The returned System.Type is exactly the same with the difference that the guid is zero.  Same C# assembly, no COM or anything funky.  I got around it by comparing Fullname but I want to be sure I'm not masking a problem by doing that.

Comment: You should probably use `Assert.AreEqual`, `Assert.Equal` or `Test.If.Value.IsEqual` for starters, depending on the unit testing framework you use. `Assert.Equals` should never work.